# How to improve the output for this factorial program?

Tags: java

[image]

Following is the required output for my Java program, I solved it but my output pattern is not like it.

```
1*1=1
1*1*2=2
1*1*2*3=6
1*1*2*3*4=24
1*1*2*3*4*5=120
```

Comment: Please paste the code here instead of image as people tend to help more if you just post your code here instead of the image.

Comment: Do factorial by recursion

Comment: This won't solve your problem, however it's a good rule of thumb to keep your code clean when debugging. You have a lot of extra lines that can be removed to clean up the code a bit.

Comment: Even though this is solved, we still require the code as text please - currently this has 3 close votes and it needs 5 to close. We are pretty strict on requiring code images to be replaced. Thanks.

Comment: Hey guys please help me to solve this factorial problem using single for loop , and not in recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have int n which is the factorial number

```
    int n=4;
    int result=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
       result = result * i;
       System.out.print("1*");
       for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
       {
           System.out.print(j+"*");
       }
       System.out.println(i+"="+result);
    }
```

The result will be:

```
1*1=1
1*1*2=2
1*1*2*3=6
1*1*2*3*4=24
```

Comment: You solved this problem by two for loops , but how to solve it using single for loop please help